# IS it possible to use geoserver WFS-T services with ArcGIS android SDK?

Tags: geoserver, android, arcgis-android

I have to use ARCGIS SDK in my project and I should edit some layers. In fact there is a sample which I can learn how ArcGIS API for android works.In it we the editable layers are from a service like this
[here](http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Recreation/FeatureServer/2)

But I dont want to use ARCGIS for server,I want to use Geoserver instead,Does ArcGIS API for android supports WFS-T or things like that?

[this](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/geometry-editor/) is the link of editing sample using ARCGIS API